# Java - filling an overlapping polygon

Tags: java, awt, polygon

I'm trying to draw a 5 point star in AWT.
Each point in the 2d grid is 72 degrees apart - so I thought I could draw the polygon using only 5 points by ordering the points 144 degrees apart, so the polygon gets fed the points in order 1,3,5,2,4

Unfortunately, this involves a lot of intersecting lines, and the end result is that there are 5 triangles with my desired colour, circling a pentagon that has not been coloured.

Looking through, it has something to do with an even-odd rule, that intersecting points will not be filled.

I need my star to be drawn dynamically, and using the specific shape described (for scaling and such).
If I manually plot the points where it intersects, I get some human error in my star's shape.

Is there any way to just turn this feature off, or failing that, is there a way to get the polygon to return an array of x[] and y[] where lines intersect so I can just draw another one inside it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Draw it with ten points, 36 degrees apart, at two alternating radii.

Comment: I mentioned that in my original post - If I manually plot the points where it intersects, I get some human error in my star's shape. The second set of points seem to have a radius of approximately 1/3 the radius of the peaks, but I don't know exactly how much it is or I'd have done this.

Answer (score 0):

Establish the 10-point [`Polygon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) in cartesian coordinates, as suggested by [relet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369113/relet) and as shown in this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon). Note how the coordinate system is centered on the origin for convenience in rotating, scaling and translating. Because [`Polygon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) implements the [`Shape`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface, the `createTransformedShape()` method of [`AffineTransform`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) may be applied. A more advanced shape library may be found [here](http://java-sl.com/shapes.html).

> Is there a way to get the polygon to return an array of `x[]` and `y[]` where lines intersect?

Although typically unnecessary, you can examine the component coordinates using a [`Shape's`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) [`PathIterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html). I found it instructive to examine the coordinates before and after invoking `createTransformedShape()`.